Semianalytic vs Analytic Partition
I am trying to figure out the difference between a semianalytic and an analytic partion.
My definition is as follow:

Let $U \subset \mathbb{R}^D$
Let $h=\{h_1, \dotsi , h_n\}$ with $h_i$ real-valued analytic functions in a neighbourhood of $U$
Let $r=\{r_1, \dotsi , r_n\}$ where $r_i$ is a relator: $r_i \in \{<,=,>\}$
Let $R(h)$ be the $3^n$ set of all possible relator combinations.
Defining:
$U_{h,r} = \{x\in U | h_i (x) r_i 0, r_i \in r,  h_i \in h\}$
Then:
$P(U, h) = \{U_{h,r} | r\in R(h)\}$ is a semi-analytic partition of $U$ subordinate to $h$

To me is clear why this set is a partition of $U$, but i don't understand why it is semianalytic and not just analytic, being that the functions $h_i$ are analytic functions.
Is there something that i am missing?
Why this is semi-analytic and not just analytic?
